# Persistent states of selectizeInput across different tabs in Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps, shinyjs

I have the following Shiny app in which I have parent and child tabs. Clicking at the child tabs creates a `selectizeInput` with different default values.
As you can see in the code, the ID for all child `selectizeInput` is same, and still, this control stores different states for each child `selectizeInput`.

I want to create a single `selectizeInput` for all child tabs and the value of this `selectizeInput` should be persistent/ same across all the tabs.

Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = FALSE,
  sidebarMenu(id = "menu_sidebar",
              conditionalPanel(
                # https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-with-tabsetpanels-and-conditionpanel-not-hiding-what-it-should/57159/3
                condition = "input.main_tab == 'mother tab' && input.group_tab == 't_child1'",
                selectizeInput(inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR"), selected = "APPLE")
              ),
              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.main_tab == 'mother tab' && input.group_tab == 't_child2'",
                selectizeInput(inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR"), selected = "ORANGE")
              ),
              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.main_tab == 'mother tab' && input.group_tab == 't_child3'",
                selectizeInput(inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR"), selected = "PEAR")
              ),
              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 1'",
                selectizeInput(inputId = "t1", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(30:40)))
              ),
              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 2'",
                selectizeInput(inputId = "t2", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(40:50)))
              )
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabsetPanel(id = "main_tab",
                selected = "mother tab",
                tabPanel(title = "tab 1", "Tab content 1"),
                tabPanel(title = "tab 2", "Tab content 2"),
                tabPanel(title = "mother tab",
                         tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "group_tab", selected = "Tab_child_2",
                                     tabPanel(title = "child_1", value = "t_child1", "Tab child content 1"),
                                     tabPanel(title = "child_2", value = "t_child2", "Tab child content 2"),
                                     tabPanel(title = "child_3", value = "t_child3", "Tab child content 3")
                         )
                )
                
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the desired behaviour? To me it seems fine. You would like to carry the selection made in one tab to the others? (if available in the choices)

Comment: ```selectizeInput``` currently shows APPLE on ```child_1``` tab, ORANGE on ```child_2``` and PEAR on ```child_3```. What I want is - the control ```selectizeInput``` should show the same value for all child tabs. When APPLE is selected in ```child_1``` then all the tabs should show ```APPLE```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd transfer the logic to the server side, as the UI part is rendered only once on startup:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = FALSE,
  sidebarMenu(id = "menu_sidebar",
              selectizeInput(inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = NULL)
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabsetPanel(id = "main_tab",
                selected = "mother tab",
                tabPanel(title = "tab 1", "Tab content 1"),
                tabPanel(title = "tab 2", "Tab content 2"),
                tabPanel(title = "mother tab",
                         tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "group_tab", selected = "Tab_child_2",
                                     tabPanel(title = "child_1", value = "t_child1", "Tab child content 1"),
                                     tabPanel(title = "child_2", value = "t_child2", "Tab child content 2"),
                                     tabPanel(title = "child_3", value = "t_child3", "Tab child content 3")
                         )
                )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(c(req(input$main_tab), input$group_tab), {
      
      if (input$main_tab == 'tab 1'){
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(30:40)), selected = isolate(input$tc))
      } else if (input$main_tab == 'tab 2'){
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(40:50)), selected = isolate(input$tc))
      }
      
      req(input$group_tab)
      if(input$main_tab == 'mother tab' && input$group_tab == 't_child1'){
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR"), selected = isolate(input$tc))
      } else if (input$main_tab == 'mother tab' && input$group_tab == 't_child2'){
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR"), selected = isolate(input$tc))
      } else if (input$main_tab == 'mother tab' && input$group_tab == 't_child3'){
        updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "tc", label = "Select by:", choices = c("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR"), selected = isolate(input$tc))
      }
      
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving this problem!